# Is it possible to put a light box in a div?

Tags: jquery, html, thumbnails, lightbox

Is it possible to have a lightbox open inside of a div instead of it covering the whole screen?

say my code is:

```
<div>
 <a href="#"><img src="image2.jpg" alt="image" /></a>
 <a href="#"><img src="image3.jpg" alt="image" /></a>
 <a href="#"><img src="image4.jpg" alt="image" /></a>
 <a href="#"><img src="image4.jpg" alt="image" /></a>
</div>
```

Those images will be clicked to open in lightbox.

Comment: which js library are you using for having a light box ?

Comment: @AshrafBashir will be using Galleria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If as mentioned in your post's comment, that you are using Galleria. 
Unfortunately this isn't provided OOTB (out of the box), you have to customize the library by adding an empty #galleria DIV inside your div. Then load some gallery data using JSON, and when the data is ready, call galleria and apply the JSON as dataSource.

As a simple alternative, you may specify the top, bottom, ...etc in CSS, by doing this you may control where the div may appear specifying dimensions, don't forget to mark them as important.

```
body .galleria-container.fullscreen{
    top:125px!important; 
    bottom:50px!important; 
    height:auto!important;
}
```